# Understanding React.JS JSON feed and how to parse

Tags: json, reactjs, api, loops

I've got the following code which is looping through an JSON file from an API and loops through some posts.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PostList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        this.setState({ posts });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
           Pulls in post slugs from Domain
          </p>

          <ul>
            { this.state.posts.map(post => <li>{post.name} - {post.username} </li>)}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This works fine, and gets the information which was needed.

Now, in my test JSON file, the format is as follows:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

But in my actual JSON file from WordPress Rest API, we have another item, named core_layout:
[JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9cP4.png)

My issue is, trying to use the same code such as `{post.name}`does not get the information needed such as core_layout->image->name.

Is there an easy way around this?

Thanks all!

EDIT:

Tried the answers below, but still no luck, get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PostList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    coreLayout: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        // const posts = res.data;
        //this.setState({ posts });
        const { posts, core_layout: coreLayout } = res.data;
        this.setState({ posts, coreLayout });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
           Pulls in post slugs from domain
          </p>

          <ul>
            { this.state.posts.map(post => <li>{post.name} - {post.core_layout.image.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Tried the below: This gets the title, but again, not the actual corelayout I need.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://zinsseruk.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1";
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          movies: res
        })
      })
  }
render() {
    let movies = this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
      <p><strong>Title:</strong> {movie.title.rendered}</p>
      <p><strong>Title:</strong> {movie.core_layout.acf_fc_layout}</p>
      </div>
    });
return (
      <div>
        <h2>Star Wars Movies</h2>
        {movies}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve? With that other WP JSON api?

Comment: At the moment, i'm getting the posts name and username. I'd like to be able to also get information from the image attached

Answer (score 1):

Replace `const posts = res.data;` with `const posts = res.data.core_layout;`. Then you'll get an array similar to what you have in your test file.

Comment: If core_layout is the root property for that API endpoint, then this seems to be the correct approach.

Comment: So in this case, would I use {post.acf_fc_layout} to get this?

Comment: const posts = res.data.core_layout;  

and

 { this.state.posts.map(post => <li>{post.acf_fc_layout}</li>)}

gives: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: You should be able to use `{ this.state.posts.map(post => <li>{post.name} - {post.username} </li>)}`. If that doesn't work, do a console.log(posts) after you set const posts, and have a look if it looks the same as your test json. It needs to be an array of objects where each object is a post.

Comment: But how would I get the info from core_layout? Would i prefix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand the JSON structure you receive from the API. Where is located `core_layout` property? Inside each `post` property as a children?

So **in the posts loop** you can use `post.core_layout.image.name` for image name, for example (and so on with other properties).

If `core_property` is at the root of the data you receive, you can load it inside your state like so:

```
  state = {
    posts: [],
    coreLayout: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        // This is equivalent of doing
        // const posts = res.data.posts
        // const coreLayout = res.data.core_layout
        const { posts, core_layout: coreLayout } = res.data;
        this.setState({ posts, coreLayout });
      })
  }
```

Then use it in your code by using local component state:

```
render() {
  ...
  // For example image name:
  console.log('image name', this.state.coreLayout.image.name)
  ...
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
PostList.render
src/App.js:35
  32 |       </p>
  33 | 
  34 |       <ul>
> 35 |         { this.state.posts.map(post => <li>{post.title.rendered} - {post.slug}</li>)}
  36 |       </ul>
  37 |   </div>
  38 | )

Comment: This is the error I get when adding this. I've added the exact code you supplied but can't seem to understand it :(

Comment: The code you share is requesting 'jsonplaceholder', not wordpress API. Can you post the full data returned by your wordpress API (res.data object on the real API, not placeholder, just remove private information). Otherwise it will be kinda difficult to do guesswork :)